# Как вывести объект при помощи массива(или другие варианты вывода объекта)?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив условно

> ["Первый", "Второй"];

Есть объект со вложенными объектами

```
{
"Первый":
0: {id: 8, branch: "Административные службы"}
"Второй": 
0: {id: 1, branch: "Администрация"} 
1: {id: 2, branch: "Администрация"}
}
```

Мне нужно все это вывести в таблицу т.е заголовок таблицы "первый" и все что из соответствующего объекта - выводится под ним.
Затем Заголовок "Второй" И выводится все из этого объекта.
Какие варианты есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, Вам нужно получить свойство объекта по строке, хранящейся в массиве.

Если так, Вы можете без проблем это сделать, просто использовав альтернативную нотацию для доступа к свойствам объекта - вместо `.` оператор `[]`. Вот пример:

```js
obj[name] // где name - как раз значение из Вашего массива
```

Тогда один из вариантов Вашей программы может выглядеть так:

```js
arr = ['first', 'second'];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length, i++) {
    console.log(obj[arr[i]]); // для первого элемента массива выведет 'first' объект
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что в значения ключей "Первый" и "Второй" - массивы. В этом случае подойдёт вариация варианта ниже

```js
const arr = ['Первый', 'Второй'];
const obj = {
  "Первый": [
    {id: 8, branch: "Административные службы"}
  ],
  "Второй": [
    {id: 1, branch: "Администрация"},
    {id: 2, branch: "Администрация"}
  ]
};

arr.forEach((arrayItem) => {
  obj[arrayItem].forEach((objectArrayItem) => {
    console.log(`У поля '${arrayItem}', где ID равен ${objectArrayItem.id}, значение равно ${objectArrayItem.branch}`)
  });
});
```